# Editing My account Order view pages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce My account "Order view" pages, I'm supposed to add a visual tracking like this:
[image]

On actual pages, to track every order, above order details:

[image]

1. 1st problem is i don't know how to add html & php code to the view order page  i tried adding hooks on functions.php but it didn't work
2. 2nd problem is that i want to get the status of every order in view order page
   (Ex: processing or delivered etc.)

Here is my functions.php code to try to achieve it:

```
    // **
//  * Add custom tracking code to the view order page
//  */
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'my_custom_tracking' );
function my_custom_tracking(){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_id  = $order->get_id(); // Get the order ID
    $parent_id = $order->get_parent_id(); // Get the parent order ID (for subscriptions…)

    $user_id   = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the costumer ID
    $user      = $order->get_user(); // Get the WP_User object

    echo $order_status  = $order->get_status(); // Get the order status 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. The *`$order_id`* variable is already included as a function argument for this hook, **but is missing in your code**.
2. You **can't use** `echo` with `$order_status = $order->get_status();`

So try instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'my_custom_tracking' );
function my_custom_tracking( $order_id ){
    // Get an instance of the `WC_Order` Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Get the order number
    $order_number  = $order->get_order_number();
    
    // Get the formatted order date created
    $date_created  = wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() );
    
    // Get the order status name
    $status_name  = wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
    
    // Display the order status 
    echo '<p>' . __("Order Status:") . ' ' . $status_name . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

If you want to **change the yellow underline texts** in your 2nd screenshot, you will have to make changes in `myaccount/view-order.php` template file:

1. First read [official documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to understand [*"how to Override templates via a theme"*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).
2. Once done and once copied WooCommerce templates to your active theme as explained on the documentation, open edit `myaccount/view-order.php` template file.
3. The changes to make are located in lines from 26 to 34:

   ```
    <p><?php
        /* translators: 1: order number 2: order date 3: order status */
        printf(
            __( 'Order #%1$s was placed on %2$s and is currently %3$s.', 'woocommerce' ),
            '<mark class="order-number">' . $order->get_order_number() . '</mark>',
            '<mark class="order-date">' . wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) . '</mark>',
            '<mark class="order-status">' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . '</mark>'
        );
    ?></p>
   ```